# React and docker during dev, see changes without restart

Tags: api-platform.com

Using a fresh new Api Platform distribution running with the default docker compose setup,
I'am not sure how to work with docker and react during developpement. I'd like to see change in browser when code is edited locally.

Should i add a kind of watcher restarting the container ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use react components but the volume configuration within the `docker-compose.yaml` file maps your localhost directory to the container directory (e.g for admin `./admin:/usr/src/admin:rw,cached`). Basically, both localhost and container share common directory.

It means any change made while developping is automatically reported to the container. It's the same as developping locally.